# Better option to mention date range in CTE query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, common-table-expression, database-performance

I just want to know about how to make my CTE query execution faster.

Option 1:

```
;with cte as
(
select Name , count(*) as TotalCount  from dbo.table 
where date_value > getdate()-120
)
select * from cte 
where count(*) > 100
```

Option 2:

```
declare @date_value date;
set @date_value = getdate()-120;

;with cte as
(
select Name , count(*) as TotalCount  from dbo.table 
where date_value > @date_value
)
select * from cte 
where count(*) > 100
```

Option 2 ran little faster than 1, only change in the above queries are with local variable and without location variable.

My question is, if we use local variable for date range, will it improve the query performance?

FYI : 
Database server : sql server 2008/R2,
Table rows : 1 million ,
Time to run : 21 mins

Any thoughts?

Comment: Pretty sure that query doesn't run. Can you post the actual query?

Comment: Before trying to performance tune (anything), have you actually measured the performance against actual goals and is the performance worse than required? If not, just write clear code and move on. If you do need to tune the performance, have you measured *where* the performance is poor? Is this the actual location of the problem? If so, does switching to the local variable form actually fix your performance issue? If so, move on. If not, look elsewhere.

Comment: I doubt you can count(*) without a group by. What's wrong with group by and "having count(*) > 300" ? No need for a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Performance is not because of CTE.Also why are you using CTE ?
Is there more script inside CTE.If yes then you should provide for full examination.
i) Finally instead of using two time Count(*),use once row_number only.

ii) Have you created index on date column ?you should .
iii) existing where condition is not going to utilize index.

Try this and please give feedback.Run several times.

```
select * from 
(
select Name ,
row_number()over(order by date_value) rn  from dbo.table 
where date_value > dateadd(d,-120,getdate())
)tbl where rn>100
```